# Delegate AVAudioPlayer for audioPlayerEndInterruption method

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

My **ViewController** name is **Mainviewcontroller** in which i m doing all the actions of **AVAudioplayer**.

If in h file i do

```
@class MainViewController;

@protocol MainViewControllerDelegate 

-(void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer;

-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer;

@end

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, InfoDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

I am confused in the above statement i m supposed to do **AVAudioPlayerDelegate** or **MainViewControllerDelegate**

If i do **@protocolAVAudioPlayerDelegate** then i **get warning in yellow stating that duplicate protocol definition of AVAudioPlayer is ignored**

when i have not defined **@protocolAVAudioPlayer** anywhere else.

Another confusion i have is that i m supposed to declare these methods in h file first only then implement in m file

```
-(void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer;

-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mis-using the @protocol construct here.  You can go ahead and drop the entire @protocol block and just implement your class.  You simply need to indcate your class is a delegate for an instance of AVAudioPlayer like this:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, InfoDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

Then when you instantiate your AVAudioPLayer object, be sure to assign the MainViewController as the delegate:

```
audioPlayInstance.delegate = self;
```

Lastly, implement the two methods you want to be called on your AVAudioPlayer instance (I called it audioPlayInstance above).  You only need to put these in your .m file, NOT you header.  The header declaration for these methods is handled by the AVAudioPlayer.h class file.

Good Luck!

Comment: i don't have any AVAudioPlayer.h class file

Comment: You do not explicitly include that file, it is pulled in when you include the AVFramework.  Here is the details:  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks so much. I was struggling with this for last two days. I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.